# how to match r' category/ (?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$' correctly as a url

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, django-views, django-urls

I am new to Django, and I am using the tango with Django book, however, I am stuck at this code  `path(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$',views.show_category, name='show_category')`,
I am trying to match the path to strings like: category/python or category/python-user-groups

when I try to go to the category page using this URL it gives the following error:

```
    Page not found (404)
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/rango/category/python
    Using the URLconf defined in rev.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    rango/ [name='index']
    rango/ about/ [name='about']
    rango/ ^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$ [name='show_category']
    ^media/(?P<path>.*)$
    The current path, rango/category/python, didn’t match any of these.
```

I figured the problem was with the category path: `path(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$')`

I need help, I have been battling with this for a day, and I can't seem to make any progress, the full codes are below.

**views.py file**

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from rango.models import Category, Page

    def index(request):
        #return HttpResponse("Rango says hey there partner <br/> <a href='/rango/about/'>About</a>")
        # Query the database for a list of ALL categories currently stored.
        # Order the categories by no. likes in descending order.
        # Retrieve the top 5 only - or all if less than 5.
        # Place the list in our context_dict dictionary
        # that will be passed to the template engine.
        category_list = Category.objects.order_by('-likes')[:5]
        context_dict = {'categories':category_list}
        return render(request, 'rango/index.html', context=context_dict)
 
    def about(request):
        #return HttpResponse("Rango says here is about the page <br/> <a href='/rango/'> Index</a>")
        context_dict = {'myname': 'Ibeh John Somtochukwu'}
        return render(request, 'rango/about.html', context=context_dict)

    #creating view for the category pages
    def show_category(request, category_name_slug):
        # Create a context dictionary which we can pass
        # to the template rendering engine.
        context_dict = {}

        try:
            # Can we find a category name slug with the given name?
            # If we can't, the .get() method raises a DoesNotExist exception.
            # So the .get() method returns one model instance or raises an exception.

            category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)

            # Retrieve all of the associated pages.
            # Note that filter() will return a list of page objects or an empty list

            pages = Page.objects.filter(category = category)

            # Adds our results list to the template context under name pages.
            context_dict['pages'] = pages
        
            # We also add the category object from
            # the database to the context dictionary.
            # We'll use this in the template to verify that the category exists.

            context_dict['category'] = category

        except Category.DoesNotExist:
            # We get here if the category does not exist
            # We don't do anything
            # The template will display no category message for us

            context_dict['category'] = None
            context_dict['pages'] = None


        return render(request, 'rango/category.html', context_dict)
```

**app urls.py file**

```
    from django.urls import path
    from rango import views
    import re
    urlpatterns = [
             path('', views.index, name='index'),
             path(r'about/', views.about, name='about'),
             path(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$',views.show_category,    name='show_category'),
        ]
```

I also have a models.py file, I don't know if the problem could be from there so I will include it:
**models.py**

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
    # Create your models here.
    class Category(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length = 128, unique=True)
        views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
            super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    
        class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class Page(models.Model):
        category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
        title = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
        url = models.URLField()
        views = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

Comment: Your regex requires a `/` char at the end, but `rango/category/python` has none. Try to remove `/` or make it optional, `/?`.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the [path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/urls/#django.urls.path) method, you don't need to use regex, as opposed to [re_path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/urls/#re-path) method.

You need to change `apps.py` from:

```py
from django.urls import path
from rango import views
import re
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path(r'about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.show_category, name='show_category'),
]
```

to this:

```py
from django.urls import path
from rango import views
import re
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('category/<category_name_slug>/', views.show_category, name='show_category'),
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly, could you recommend a book or a tutorial for django and regex, it seems the book works on the old version of django

Comment: @IbehJohn you could always look at the docs for [how to use re_path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions) and a great tutorial for Django is [Corey Schafer's playlist](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p). Even though it's outdated, still relevant to date.